# AWS RDS - Is it possible to use serverless & secrets manager & data-api & query editor?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've created several databases in AWS RDS, however with this new one I'm running into an issue. I would like to create an Aurora Postgres DB and to  use:

- serverless (v1 or v2)
- Secrets manager
- Data API
- Query Editor

In the documentation it indicates that you can't use Query Editor and Serverless v2, so we have to use serverless v1 (i would be very happy to proven wrong on this BTW)

For the postgresSQL version we pick v13.9, because that is the last one compatible with serverless v1.

Now, it seems that using secrets manager and serverless v1 are also incompatible with each other (selecting one disables the other).

Is there any way to have all four of these requirements met? Or should I just pick the most important 3 requirements and move on?

Comment: it does work, we do this regularly. I connect via Query Editor in the console using secrets manager, and the Data API is enabled. 
Maybe check that you're using the right secret?